# Google Calendar PHP API can not create calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am having some issues using Google Calendar API using the PHP client library.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
define("CLIENT_ID", "blah blah blah");
define("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME", "blah blahblah");   
define("KEY_FILE", "keykeykey.p12");

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar Sample");
$client->setUseObjects(true);

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{
   $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                                 SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                 array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
                                 $key)
);

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
try
{
    $calendar = new Google_Calendar();
    $calendar->setSummary('test');

    $createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);
    var_dump($createdCalendar);
}
catch(Google_ServiceException $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($client->getAccessToken()) 
{
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
?>
```

The dump of the $createdCalendar is as follows:

```
object(Google_Calendar)[15]
public 'kind' => string 'calendar#calendar' (length=17)
public 'description' => null
public 'summary' => string 'test' (length=3)
public 'etag' => string '"wT71Iy7ZAyY0SAhLu4jxO8w9qqM/zHZjSmLgdGM-FmXSbf2H0YONYb0"' (length=57)
public 'location' => null
public 'timeZone' => null
public 'id' => string '8ejg8n6j1j9utuuh6954jm18lk@group.calendar.google.com' (length=52)
```

This shows that the calendar was created succesfully because an ID was provided by google. However this calendar does not show up in the list of Calendars when I open google calendar in my web browser.

Any ideas?

BTW, I know for sure the setup of my 2 Legged OAuth2 is working because if I replace the block of code between //////////////   with the following, it works fine

```
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2012-12-15T16:00:00.000-08:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2012-12-15T19:00:00.000-08:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('testEmail@gmail.com');

$attendees = array($attendee1);
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

Comment: this is using V3 of the calendar API

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Have you checked the Apache `error.log`?

Comment: After that piece of code runs, shouldn't the new calendar that was created show up under 'My Calendars' in google calendar website?

Comment: Have you imported it in your Google Calendars account?

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with importing the calendars...

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `google`, `calendar` and `api` doesn't mean you're talking about the Google Calendar API.  There is a separate, single tag for that.

Comment: Yet I don't even understand if your problem is with your code or with using Google Calendars.

Comment: I've never done this (so not posting as an answer unless it works), but I presume you need to add the calendar resource (for which you have the ID) into a users CalendarList (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert). This sets things such as the colour, default reminders etc and presumably allows that user to see it.

Comment: Have you tried logging in and logging out from your google account?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that similar code of mine creates calendars for google api user (`NNNNNNNNNNNN@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) but not me. Check out 'id' of the first existing calendar and you will see `NNNNNNNNNNNN@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.